# Use constraints to run multiple instances of traefik on one machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, traefik

I'm trying to use docker and traefik as a load-balancer for a simple blue/green deployment setup and I want to be able to have multiple instances of traefik up at the same time. From what I understand I have to set constraints with:
`` --providers.docker.constraints=Label(`key`,`value`) ``
but I couldn't figure out what label I have to put on my services so traefik doesn't ignore them. The docs were very vague on this and google hasn't been much help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you need you can use any label (apart from already existing Traefik's config labels, such as `traefik.http.routers`). Main idea is that in Traefik configuration the label and value is specified, thus services with exactly same pair of label/value will be allowed to be managed by this particular instance of Traefik.

So, the basic example could be:

```
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.3
    command:
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.constraints=Label(`custom.label`,`custom-value`)"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  custom_service:
    image: ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "custom.label=custom-value"
```

I used such approach with `custom-value` provided via environment variable which allowed me to run multiple docker-compose instances with Traefik proxying only services from it's corresponding docker-compose cluster.

[Docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/docker/#constraints)